# Rails - how to refactor this code, that queries on some optional arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style, refactoring

How can I refactor this method, without changing its signature (i.e, cannot change it to receive an options hash)

```
def find_or_create_user(name, email=nil, age=nil, gender=nil)
    users = User.where(name: name)
    users = users.where(email: email) if email
    users = users.where(age: age) if age
    users = users.where(gender: gender) if gender
    users.first_or_initialize
end
```

Comment: What do you want to refactor?

Comment: it seems to be not so elegant, and violating DRY

Answer (score 3):

You could really just get away with [`first_or_create_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) with this:

```
@user = User.first_or_create_by name: "Name", age: 54, email: "email@email.com"
```

---

If you really wanted to roll your own, you'd have to use a [`class method`](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) - *not* the `instance method` you have now:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.find_or_create *args
      args.extract_options!
      find_or_create_by args
   end
end
```

This should allow you to create:

```
User.find_or_create name: "Richard", age: "5", email: "tester@tester.com"
```

... which is basically the same as `find_or_create_by`